# SQL returning max value from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following code returns:

```
personID  lastname  firstname  number
-------------------------------------
  17520   doe       john       0192
```

Code:

```
select 
    personID, lastname, firstname, number
from 
    (select distinct
         max(sm.personID) as personID, 
         sm.lastName, 
         ISNULL(sm.alias, sm.firstName) as firstname,       
         max(sm.schoolNumber) as number, 
         max(assignmentID) as assignmentID
     from 
         staffmember sm
     where 
         (sm.endDate >= GetDate() or sm.endDate is null)
         and (sm.startDate <= GetDate())
     group by 
         sm.lastName, sm.firstName, sm.alias) as query
where 
    1 = 1
```

If I pull out the subquery and remove the max aggregates from `schoolNumber` and `assignmentID` and add `assignmentID` to the select so that the query looks like this:

```
select distinct
max(sm.personID) as personID, 
sm.lastName, 
ISNULL(sm.alias, sm.firstName) as firstname,
sm.schoolNumber as number, 
sm.assignmentID as assignmentID
from staffmember sm
where (sm.endDate >= GetDate() or sm.endDate is null)
and (sm.startDate <= GetDate())
and personID = '17520'
group by sm.lastName, sm.firstName, sm.alias, sm.schoolNumber, sm.assignmentID
```

The query returns:

```
personID  lastname  firstname  number  assignmentID
----------------------------------------------------
17520     doe       john       0192    1354
17520     doe       john       0103    1538
```

I need the original query to return:

```
personID  lastname  firstname  number
-------------------------------------
17520     doe       john       0103
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT, since the GROUP BY returns no duplicate rows.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functions there...)

Comment: @jarlh SSMS 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below using correlated subquery

```
select sm.personID as personID, sm.lastName, ISNULL(sm.alias, sm.firstName) as firstname,
sm.schoolNumber as number, 
sm.assignmentID as assignmentID
from staffmember sm
where (sm.endDate >= GetDate() or sm.endDate is null)
and (sm.startDate <= GetDate())
and personID = '17520' 
and assignmentID in 
    (select max(assignmentID) from staffmember sm1 where sm.personID =sm1.personid 
      and sm1.personID = '17520')
```